# Jackson Xml - how to use builder

Tags: java, jackson, builder

According to the current information at the [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/blob/2.17/README.md) github site, it is possible to configure the serializer using builder style construction. However what I don't see is what are the configuration options that you can use with this style.

From what I've seen, it looks like you can only include NON EMPTY fields when using JSON, but not using Xml. Is that right?

In particular I'd like to serialize some POJO data to XML and exclude Empty fields using version 2.15. Does anyone know how to use this feature or point me to the documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper()
   .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)
   .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
   .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
   .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_INDEX, true);
```

See [SerializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html) and [DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) for available serialization / deserialization options